# How to know what serializer_class is used

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I define a serializer class in the `get_serializer_class` function. In my update function, how can I know which serializer class is selected? What is the best practice for this?

Simple code:

```
class SomeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = SomeModel

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        # here I define my serializer class, let's say between FirstSerializerClass and SecondSerializerClass

    def update(self, request):
        if self.serializer_class == FirstSerializerClass:
            # I checked this way, but it didn't work for me
```

Comment: You just need to confirm which serializer you want to use in `get_serializer_class`, you can refer to `UpdateModelMixin`, you can see that the `self.get_serializer` method is used.

Comment: The isinstance() function returns True if the specified object is of the specified type, otherwise False.